# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x}{x+e^{-nx}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I have found there is pointwise convergence in $(-\infty,0] $ and using Weierstrass theorem uniformly convergence in $(-\infty,a],a<0$. Can I use Leibniz to prove uniformly convergence in $(-\infty,0]$?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot, since the Leibniz test is for convergence of numerical series, not for uniform convergence of series of functions. But you can apply [Dirichlet's test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence).